# get all row from left table with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two Table and i want to get data from both table.
Table_1

```
ID   Name
1   Test11
2   Test22
3   Test33
4   Test44
5   Test55
6   Test66
```

Table_2

```
ID   Class  Price
1     X1      10
6     X1      20
4     X1      30
6     X3      20
1     X2      10
2     X2      10
```

I want all row from left table with where Class name

Result

```
if Class='X1'

ID   Name     Class  Price
1   Test11     X1     10
2   Test22     X1
3   Test33     X1
4   Test44     X1     30
5   Test55     X1
6   Test66     X1     20
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Any efforts? Also it is unclear how can you get this result: `2   Test22     X1`. Based on your input data it is impossible even if your tables has `ID <-> ID` relationship because of record `2     X2` in Table_2

Comment: @AndyKorneyev sorry for editing, please share your review.

Comment: A simple `LEFT JOIN` would solve this.

Comment: What is the price value for 2   Test22     X1 ??,3   Test33     X1??,5   Test55     X1??

Comment: Don't understand why, in your desired result, `Class` is not empty when `Price` is empty...

Comment: that's my requirement, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple `LEFT JOIN`. You just have to assign `X1` as your `Class` in your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    Class = 'X1',
    t2.Price
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Class = 'X1'
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Name       Class Price
----------- ---------- ----- -----------
1           Test11     X1    10
2           Test22     X1    NULL
3           Test33     X1    NULL
4           Test44     X1    30
5           Test55     X1    NULL
6           Test66     X1    20
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: Are you sure you copied it right? It works fine on my machine.

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell me if it's the first `=`? You're using sql-server right?

Comment: Can you show me your query?

Comment: SELECT
    t1.Name,
    t2.Class='X1',
    t2.Price
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Class = 'X1'

Comment: Remove `t2.` from `t2.Class = 'X1'`. It should be `Class = 'X1'`.

Comment: you are right, when i remove t2 from  t2.Class it run successfully.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: these all are very cheap, that do my question is unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82896/discussion-between-wewesthemenace-and-user3441151).